# cant find Oracle home ,it shows already exist

Tags: database, oracle

[https://imgur.com/a/vqkQStu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWzcW.png)what  can do
please help

oracle database home not finding please tell me how to solve this error in new to programming language plz help me to find out the error
also tell me how to solve this error in new to programming language  help me to find out the error

Answer (score 0):

The message is about "Oracle Home user already exist", not "Oracle Home already exist".

Try using the option "Use Existing Windows User", or also delete that user.

Comment: I delete the Existing Windows User, not working still , i watch youtube videos all methods to delete still cant figureout